# How to rewrite URL in .htaccess [seo permlink]

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My file is `category.php?id=` and here is my code:

```
<a href="category.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></a>
```

I want to change url to `site.com/category/title-here/id`. How can I rewrite it with `.htaccess` ?

Here is my `.htaccess` for `detail.php` page and it is working fine as `site.com/detail.php?id=1` to `site.com/title-here/1`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.name.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://name.com/$1 [L,R=301]

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteRule ^/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ detail.php?title=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ detail.php?id=$1

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: what already do you try to do this ?

Comment: read again q i updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.name.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://name.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^category/([^\.]+)$ category.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ detail.php?title=$1&id=$2

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ detail.php?id=$1
Options -Indexes
```

Now Your URL is Showing Like this `http://name.com/category/your-title-here?id=1`

Comment: @rohaan-ahmed if they work fine please mark on correct

Answer (score 1):

As for detail page you can add the same rule with a `category` prefix:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.name.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://name.com/$1 [L,R=301]

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ category.php?title=$1&$id=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ detail.php?title=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ detail.php?id=$1

Options -Indexes
```